# Value cannot be Null. Parameter name: input error during streamreader

Tags: regex, vb.net, streamreader

If I am just reading in a file, why wouldnt it know to just end if there is nothing left or if it is null? I believe the error is thrown when its trying to do the match for 'line' and there isnt any more lines. Below is the code of when it reads in the file:

```
    Dim Directory1 As String = "C:\Perl_Scripts\"
    Dim Ext2Find As String = "850_*.txt"

    If System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Directory1, Ext2Find, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length > 0 Then
        Dim Return_Val() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Directory1, Ext2Find, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Directory1, Ext2Find, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length - 1
            'MsgBox(Ext2Find & " was found! " & Return_Val(i))

            Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\\Perl_scripts\\850_7703844115CH_54550937_20190218_062619.txt")
                Dim line As String
                ' Read and display lines from the file until the end of  
                ' the file is reached. 
                line = sr.ReadLine()
                While (line <> Nothing)
                    line = sr.ReadLine()
                    If Regex.IsMatch(line, "\b40\S*") Then  
                        MsgBox(line)
                    Else
                        MsgBox("THERES NO MATCH")
                    End If
                End While
            End Using

        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox(Ext2Find & " was not found!")
    End If
```

Let Me know if you need to see the whole sub. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to imagine that you wouldn;t have seen the issue here if you had actually debugged your code, so i can only conclude that you didn't debug your code. You should NEVER post a question here without debugging first. If you don't know how to use the debugger properly, i.e. setting breakpoints and examining state while stepping through code, then you should stop what you're doing and learn before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what your code actually does here:

```vb
line = sr.ReadLine()
While (line <> Nothing)
    line = sr.ReadLine()
    If Regex.IsMatch(line, "\b40\S*") Then  'Looks for Menard files
        MsgBox(line)
    Else
        MsgBox("THERES NO MATCH")
    End If
End While
```

You read a line, check whether it is `Nothing` and, if it isn't, you immediately discard that line and read another and use that. You then test whether the second line you read was `Nothing`, then read another line and then use it. How does that make sense? You never use the first line and then you use every subsequent line before testing whether it's `Nothing`.

This is what happens when you don't have an algorithm to compare your code to. If you had such an algorithm then it would be obvious that you're doing things in the wrong order. That code should be like this:

```vb
line = sr.ReadLine()

While (line <> Nothing)
    If Regex.IsMatch(line, "\b40\S*") Then  'Looks for Menard files
        MsgBox(line)
    Else
        MsgBox("THERES NO MATCH")
    End If

    line = sr.ReadLine()
End While
```

Now the sequence of events is read the line, check whether it's `Nothing`, use the line, repeat.

Of course, this is all moot because you shouldn't read the file like that anyway. You should do this:

```vb
For Each line In File.ReadLines("C:\Perl_scripts\850_7703844115CH_54550937_20190218_062619.txt")
    If Regex.IsMatch(line, "\b40\S*") Then  'Looks for Menard files
        MsgBox(line)
    Else
        MsgBox("THERES NO MATCH")
    End If
Next
```

Notice that I didn't use double slashes either, because this is VB and that's wrong.

EDIT:

Note that that last code snippet calls `ReadLines` and not `ReadAllLines`. Both will work and there's no practical difference in many (most?) cases. The difference is that `ReadAllLines` will read the whole file into an array first and then you will loop over that, while `ReadLines` will return one line at a time as the looping is done. That is especially advantageous for large files because it means that you won't need to store the whole file in memory the whole time.

It also means that, if appropriate, you can break out of the loop without reading the rest of the file. Imagine that you have a file with a million lines and you're searching for something that appears in the first line. `ReadAllLines` would create an array with a million elements first, then start the loop and find the match in the first line. On the other hand, `ReadLines` would read the first line and return it, the match would be found and the rest of the file would never be read. That's a big saving on memory and time.